# No entiendo el array en php

Tags: php, array

```
<?php 

$empleados = array(
    array('Powell, Alfredo','Administrativo',5500),
    array('Pérez, Verónica','Administrativo',5200),
    array('Goldstein, Juan','Recursos Humanos',6800),
    array('Giaccomo, Walter','Recursos Humanos',6200),
    array('Armani, Luis','Compras',10500),
    array('Sarlanga, Horacio','Administrativo',5500),
    array('Juárez, Alicia','Compras',7500),
    array('Toselli, Agustina','Mantenimiento',5800),
    array('Gómez, Valeria','Sistemas',4700),
    array('Valverde, Emiliano','Recursos Humanos',5800),
    array('Domínguez, Carlos','Mantenimiento',4900),
    array('Carranza, Saúl','Administrativo',9500),
);
$gana_mas = "";
$salario = 0;

foreach ($empleados as $empleado) {
    foreach ($empleado as $valor) {
        if ($valor > $salario) {
            $salario = $valor;
            $gana_mas = $empleado[0]; //NO ENTIENDO ESTO!
        }

    }
        echo '<br />';
        #echo $salario;
}


echo "El salario mas alto es: $salario <br />";
echo "El salario mas alto es de: $gana_mas";
```

Quiero mostrar el nombre del trabajador que cobra más, pero no entiendo por qué tengo que acceder por $empleado[0] y no puedo por valor[0]. Hasta donde entiendo $empleado es cada fila del array $empleados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$empleado` es un array que contiene `('Powell, Alfredo','Administrativo',5500)` la primera vez que se entra en el bucle foreach. Te lo dibujo para que lo veas mejor:

`$empleado[0]` = Powell, Alfredo

`$empleado[1]` = Administrativo

`$empleado[2]` = 5500

Ojo aquí, porque esta comparando el salario a todos los elementos del array `$empleado`. En cualquier caso una vez comprobado que el `$valor` es el mayor salario, coge el contenido de `$empleado[0]` y lo asigna a `$gana_mas`.

`$empleado[0]` contiene el primer registro del array, que en este caso es "Powell, Alfredo".

---

La segunda vez que pase por el foreach el valor de `$empleado` será `('Pérez, Verónica','Administrativo',5200)` y el valor de `$empleado[0]` será "Pérez, Verónica".

Comment: Pero si puedo acceder a posiciones de array de esta forma $empleado[0], entonces de que me sirve el $valor?

Comment: De nada en realidad, podrías preguntárselo a `$empleado[2]` en realidad.

Comment: el $valor te funcionaria si es un array asociativo

Answer (score 0):

Empecemos con que esa lógica no es correcta, ya que está comparando todo el array con un valor numérico, cuando sabemos que el salario se encuentra en una posición fija del array. El código más acertado sería el siguiente:

```
$gana_mas = "";
$salario = 0;
foreach ($empleados as $empleado) {
    if ($empleado[2] > $salario) {
        $salario = $empleado[2];
        $gana_mas = $empleado[0];
    }

}
    echo '<br />';
    #echo $salario;
```

La linea que comentas que no entiendes es simplemente almacenar el nombre del empleado que gana más dinero, que se encuentra siempre en la posición 0 del array $empleado.

$empleado[2] contiene el valor del salario, por lo que así tambien ahorrar un foreach.

Comment: Tengo que sacar el salario mas alto de todo el array. Por eso tengo que usar el otro foreach.

Comment: Sí, pero con un solo bucle puedes sacarlo. Ese segundo bucle solo recorre cada valor dentro del array $empleado, que son el nombre del empleado, el departamento y el sueldo

Comment: He corregido el indice en el código que he puesto, que estaba pensando en otra cosa y puse indice 4 en lugar de indice 2, que es el que corresponde al sueldo

Comment: @JoseFranciscoDominguezPalac El código tiene errores, la variable $valor no existe ahí.

Comment: @Flowen cierto es, corregido